# Istio - Grafana with SubPath "if you're seeing this grafana has failed to load its application files"

Tags: kubernetes, grafana, istio, azure-aks

I am using Istio with Grafana enabled in AKS and want to use a subPath like `example.com/metrics/grafana`. The provided [istio documentation](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/observability/gateways/) only explains how to use it without a subpath, but a subdomain. But this is not an option here.

According to this [grafana tutorial](https://grafana.com/tutorials/run-grafana-behind-a-proxy/#1) I have to set

```
domain = example.com
root_url = %(protocol)s://%(domain)s:%(http_port)s/metrics/grafana/
serve_from_sub_path = true
```

so I have set them in the `IstioOperator`:

```
apiVersion: install.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: IstioOperator
spec:
  profile: default
  values:
    [...]
    grafana:
      # Enable Grafana deployment for analytics and monitoring dashboards
      enabled: true
      env:
        GF_SERVER_ROOT_URL: "%(protocol)s://%(domain)s/metrics/grafana/"
        GF_SERVER_DOMAIN: "example.com"
        GF_SERVER_SERVE_FROM_SUB_PATH: "true"
```

Additionally I have set up a `VirtualService`

```
    - name: grafana-route
      match:
        - uri:
            prefix: /metrics/grafana/
      route:
        - destination:
            host: grafana.istio-system.svc.cluster.local
            port:
              number: 3000
```

But when I visit example.com/metrics/grafana I keep getting the message:

> If you’re seeing this Grafana has failed to load its application files
>
> This could be caused by your reverse proxy settings.
>
> If you host grafana under subpath make sure your grafana.ini root_path setting includes subpath
>
> If you have a local dev build make sure you build frontend using: npm run dev, npm run watch, or npm > > run build
>
> Sometimes restarting grafana-server can help

Anyone knows what the problem might be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`serve_from_sub_path` must be set to `false`.

```
    grafana:
      # Enable Grafana deployment for analytics and monitoring dashboards
      enabled: true
      env:
        GF_SERVER_ROOT_URL: "%(protocol)s://%(domain)s/metrics/grafana/"
        GF_SERVER_DOMAIN: "example.com"
        GF_SERVER_SERVE_FROM_SUB_PATH: "false"
```

Furthermore the uri has to be rewritten:

```
    - name: grafana-route
      match:
        - uri:
            exact: /management/grafana
        - uri:
            prefix: /management/grafana/
      rewrite:
        uri: /
      route:
        - destination:
            host: grafana.istio-system.svc.cluster.local
            port:
              number: 3000
```